# Вывод элементов главной и побочной диагонали матрицы(java)

Tags: java, массивы, алгоритм, циклы, матрицы

Дана матрица N * N. Вывести элементы главной и побочной диагонали в обратном порядке.

**Формат входных данных:**
Первая строка содержит целое число N. 1 <= N <= 300. Далее N строк содержат по N целых чисел разделенных пробелом. -10^9 <= Xi <= 10^9.

**Формат выходных данных:**
На первой строке N чисел разделенные пробелом - элементы главной диагонали. На второй строке N чисел разделенные пробелом - элементы побочной диагонали.

**Пример:**

> **Входные данные**

```
3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

> **Выходные данные**

```
 9 5 1
 7 5 3
```

Главную диагональ я нашел и вывел. Не могу понять, как вывести побочную.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = s.nextInt();
    int m = n;
    int k = args.length;
    int[][] a = new int[n][m];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            a[i][j] = s.nextInt();
        }
    }
    for (int i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if (i == j){
                System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
            }
        }
    } System.out.println();
}
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
int maxIdx = a.length - 1;

// Главная
for (int i = maxIdx; i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.print(a[i][i] + " ");
}
System.out.println();

// Побочная
for (int i = maxIdx; i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.print(a[i][maxIdx - i] + " ");
}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 3
вывело только 9 5 1 
3

Comment: В общем,да,побочная все равно не выводится @Anton Shchyrov

Comment: @ПавелКулагин Исправил ошибку

Comment: Работает,спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

главная:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (Math.min(ints[0].length, ints.length)); i++) {
    System.out.print(ints[i][i] + " ");
}
```

побочная:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (Math.min(ints[0].length, ints.length)); i++) {
    System.out.print(ints[i][ints[0].length-i-1]+" ");
}
```